# How to unify the data format of csv file on the same column

Tags: python, csv, pandas

my csv is from bloomberg, its format is like this:

```
Time Interval,Close,Net Chg,Open,High,Low,Tick Count,Volume
05SEP2012,,,,,,,
09:15 - 09:30,97.722,0,98.34,98.34,97.722,2,37155
09:30 - 09:45,97.899,0.177,98.164,98.164,97.281,102,101725
09:45 - 10:00,97.722,-0.177,97.899,97.899,97.193,32,39874
06SEP2012,,,,,,,
09:15 - 09:30,98.076,0.883,98.076,98.076,98.076,1,22429
09:30 - 09:45,97.193,-0.883,97.634,97.987,97.104,72,67741
09:45 - 10:00,96.928,-0.265,97.193,97.193,96.751,80,148963...
```

If I want to unify the format so that [the date XX/XX/201X+ the time XX:XX-XX:XX] becomes a key for matching,it may be looks like:

```
Date,Time Interval,Close,Net Chg,Open,High,Low,Tick Count,Volume
05SEP2012,,,,,,,,
05SEP2012,09:15 - 09:30,97.722,0,98.34,98.34,97.722,2,37155
05SEP2012,09:30 - 09:45,97.899,0.177,98.164,98.164,97.281,102,101725
05SEP2012,09:45 - 10:00,97.722,-0.177,97.899,97.899,97.193,32,39874
06SEP2012,,,,,,,,
06SEP2012,09:15 - 09:30,98.076,0.883,98.076,98.076,98.076,1,22429
06SEP2012,09:30 - 09:45,97.193,-0.883,97.634,97.987,97.104,72,67741
06SEP2012,09:45 - 10:00,96.928,-0.265,97.193,97.193,96.751,80,148963...
```

May anyone tell me What code I should write please? I am very new to programming and trying to write a python program about pair-trading for a school project.The content of this [article](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Backtesting-An-Intraday-Mean-Reversion-Pairs-Strategy-Between-SPY-And-IWM) is my major reference, and when inputting the data, it can't input the csv data we collect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for python 3

 import csv
    with open('data.csv', 'r', newline='') as f,  open('data_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
        reader = csv.reader(f,quotechar='"')
        # read headers
        headers = next(reader)
        # insert new column name
        headers.insert(0,"Date")

        w = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',' )
        # write headers
        w.writerow(headers)

        for line in f:
            if ',,,' in line:
                newcolumn = line
                newcolumn = line.strip()
                newcolumn = newcolumn.replace(',','')
                f_out.write(line)
            else:
                line = newcolumn + ',' + line.strip()
                line = line.split(',')
                w.writerow(line)

for python 2.7

import csv
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f,  open('data_out.csv', 'wb') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f,quotechar='"')
    # read headers
    headers = next(reader)
    # insert new column name
    headers.insert(0,"Date")

    w = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',' )
    # write headers
    w.writerow(headers)

    for line in f:
        if ',,,' in line:
            newcolumn = line
            newcolumn = line.strip()
            newcolumn = newcolumn.replace(',','')
            f_out.write(line)
        else:
            line = newcolumn + ',' + line.strip()
            line = line.split(',')
            w.writerow(line)

    Date,Time Interval,Close,Net Chg,Open,High,Low,Tick Count,Volume
    05SEP2012,,,,,,,
    05SEP2012,09:15 - 09:30,97.722,0,98.34,98.34,97.722,2,37155
    05SEP2012,09:30 - 09:45,97.899,0.177,98.164,98.164,97.281,102,101725
    05SEP2012,09:45 - 10:00,97.722,-0.177,97.899,97.899,97.193,32,39874
    06SEP2012,,,,,,,
    06SEP2012,09:15 - 09:30,98.076,0.883,98.076,98.076,98.076,1,22429
    06SEP2012,09:30 - 09:45,97.193,-0.883,97.634,97.987,97.104,72,67741
    06SEP2012,09:45 - 10:00,96.928,-0.265,97.193,97.193,96.751,80,148963
```

Comment: sorry to mention that I use python 2.7, may u translate the code into 2.7?

Comment: @YuiHungCheung no problem. I have added the code now for 2.7 also, it has been tested on 2.7.

Answer (score -1):

```
# First open your file:
csv_file = open(path_to_file, 'r')

# Initialize list to hold the rows
rows = []

# For each line in your file, split values into a list and add to the rows list
for line in csv_file:
    rows.append(line.split(','))
```

Now each row element will be a list with similar structure. You can compare similar "cells" - say, first column in first and second row by:

rows[1][0] vs rows[2][0],  remember that list indexes are zero-based.

Hope this will get you on your way,

cheers

Comment: This is a very basic solution that may give you what you need and above all is very easy to understand. But the downside is that you won't get the headers. For that, you might want to consider the csv module as suggested by LetzerWille.